# How to set dynamic column name to set value in UPDATE statement of SQL Query on the basis of condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

Table structure : table name :  `DETAIL_BOX`

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| sn (Number) | name (varchar2) | date1 (date)        | date2 (date)        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2         | Ram             | 26.11.2015 00:00:00 |    NULL             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   3         | Sita            | NULL                | 26.11.2015 00:00:00 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need single SQL update statement with dynamic column 
name depends upon case.

**Case:** If **date2** is null update date in **date1**
otherwise update date value in **date2**

SQL statements like below are possible or not ?

- **To update row having sn=2**
- There is an any query like below query ?

  `UPDATE DETAIL_BOX SET name='Gita', NVL(date2,date1)=to_date('2015-10-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') WHERE sn=2`
- **Expectation :** 
  update value of date in field **date1** because **date2** field is NULL in row having sn=2.
- **To update row having sn=3**
- There is an any query like below query ?

  `UPDATE DETAIL_BOX SET name='Krish', NVL(date2,date1)=to_date('2015-10-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') WHERE sn=3`
- **Expectation :** 
  update value of date in field **date2** because **date2** field is not NULL in row having sn=3.

**Note:** Above UPDATE sql queries are not correct. I just put these query to ask any Update statements are possible to set dynamic column name to set value.

Comment: When you say expectation update value of date in field - which field? You have 2 date columns.

Comment: @BeanFrog Please see question , now updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put two answers (by BeanFrog and Prabhat Sharma) together. In my opinion it's good solution to update column to a new value or to itself in depend on criteria.

```
update detail_box
set
   name = decode(sn, 2, 'Gita', 3, 'Krish', name),
   date1 = (case when sn = 2 and date2 is null then to_date('2015-10-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') else date1 end),
   date2 = (case when sn = 3 and date2 is null then to_date('2015-10-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') else date2 end)
```

Please note, `decode` function is specific to ORACLE database. It could be changed to `case` structure if you want to have common code regardless to RDBMS vendor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where sn comes in, but hopefully the general method will help.

Update both fields in your update statement, but either set them to themselves or to the new date based on a case statement:

```
UPDATE DETAIL_BOX SET date2= case when date2 is null then date2 else to_date('2015-10-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') end 
    , date1 = case when date 2 is null then to_date('2015-10-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') else date1 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see if this helps .

Idea is to include all columns in one update statement and then on the basis of your criteria you can decide whether to let them change or let them remain as is for a particular row .

```
            UPDATE detail_box 
            SET NAME = CASE WHEN sn = 2 THEN 'gita' WHEN sn= 3 THEN 'Krish' ELSE NAME END  , 
            date1 = CASE WHEN date1 IS NULL AND sn = 2 THEN date1 WHEN date1 IS NOT NULL AND sn = 2 THEN to_date('24-Nov-2014') ELSE date1 END , 
            date2=CASE WHEN date2 IS NULL and sn= 3 THEN date2  WHEN date2 IS NULL and sn= 3 then to_date('24-Nov-2014') else date2  END
```